# How to Disable FRP using ADB Sideload?

Tags: android, adb, frp, samsung

my issue is pretty much in the title.
I have been trying to remove the FRP of a samsung Flip 3.
I set up ADB, downloaded the CLI tools with the right version. (I am not using Android Studio)

Can anyone help
Thank you in advance :))

When I try to execute any command in the ADB CLI it returns **error: closed** .
This happened when I tried to execute these commands:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gsf.login/
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/secure --bind
```

It happens with pretty much every command that I tried. I think it's due to the "sideload" mode of the phone when I execute adb devices .
I overall need any way of removing the FRP, maybe my best shot would be if I could enable USB Debugging from the recovery screen.

Comment: Off topic on StackOverflow. See: [Can I remove FRP with Heimdall/Odin?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204451/3573)

Answer (score 0):

If you be able to set USB debugging to enabled, then it is easier. But we assume that you can't even to log in to your device to do so. Then following instruction to enable USB debugging as a prerequisite (not necessarily as there are some magic software out there) that is from someone on stack exchange and I just copy that here could be helpful.

Enable USB debugging through recovery mode and ADB sideload
Asked 2 years, 3 months ago
Modified 2 years, 3 months ago
Viewed 4k times

3

This is a follow up question to this one. Basically, I intend to somehow use this command to remove the lock screen:

> adb sideload customROM.zip
> But, the customROM.zip should be something like described here to enable USB debugging. The problem is, those steps are incomplete:

Steps to Enable USB Debugging Using Recovery Mode

Unzip the stock ROM.

Within the extracted folder, you will find the system.img well extract it too using Ext4 Unpacker

Also, extract the Update-SuperSU.v1.65.zip file.

Now open the folder where you have extracted the system.img files

Grab any .apk file from this folder and change the extension from .apk to .zip

And Copy the RSA Certificated to the Update-SuperSU.v1.65 folder (delete previous files if exist)

Also, copy the build.prop to the system folder located within Update-SuperSU.v1.65 folder

Locate the update-script file within this folder and edit it using Notepad++

You need to update the build.prop file after adding the following line at the bottom persist.service.adb.enable=1

Next step is updating SQLite Database

Which can be done by adding the following code to the update-script file sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "UPDATE global SET value=1 WHERE name='adb_enabled'"

Cheers! You have Enabled USB Debugging Now you can install your custom or stock ROM using ADB – USB Debugging

Although the above steps seem incomplete, they look convincing that there might be a way to modify a stock ROM to enable USB debugging by:

> adb sideload modified-stock-ROM-which-just-enables-USB-debugging-and-does-nothing-else.zip
> Is there any better explanation than those steps?

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230999/enable-usb-debugging-through-recovery-mode-and-adb-sideload

https://www.isrgrajan.com/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-using-recovery-mode.html